# Is it possible to add img title attribute as dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add the title attribute as dynamically , or title attribute as same as image url
Code is as below..
Is it possible?

```
<img ng-src="{{ bundle.display_based_order.1.url }}" class="svg_icons_bundle_listing_page" alt="bundle" title="bundle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the wording of your question isn't quite clear to me, but if you want to have a dynamically rendered title attribute on an element, just use the `{{ }}` syntax to bind it to some property in your $scope.

```html
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{imgHash}}" title="{{imgTitle}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), like `title="{{bundle.display_based_order.1.title ?? bundle.display_based_order.1.url}}"` - which basicallys says *use the `.title` data point if available, otherwise use the `.url`*

```
<img ng-src="{{ bundle.display_based_order.1.url }}" class="svg_icons_bundle_listing_page" alt="bundle" title="{{bundle.display_based_order.1.title ?? bundle.display_based_order.1.url}}"/>
```